# Is it possible for an asteroid to shoot through the earth like a bullet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision

Is it possible for an asteroid to shoot through a planet like a bullet ? 
If so how much force would be necessary for it too go through and out the other side .
Using the earth diameter as a base measurement.
Assuming the asteroid is the size of a small town, or even smaller .

Also would this be an issue of speed ?

Comment: No, it's not. :-)

Comment: Please note that this is not a site where people do calculations for you.  It is a site for students and researchers of Physics & Astronomy, and you are expected to apply your knowledge of physics and demonstrate an effort to work through the problem.

Comment: Which is why my question is structured to see how one would go about tackling a problem like this . But thanks .

Comment: *"How much force is [...]"* Force is not the word you want there. And re-phrasing the question doesn't change the fact that you can't punch a hole in the planet without substantially disrupting the body. We're talking a minimum energy only a couple of orders of magnitude less than the binding energy of the planet. It simply *won't* do [what you are envisioning](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266057/how-much-force-speed-was-necessary-to-pull-this-off).

Answer (score 1):

When an asteroid collides with the Earth at a speed of, say, 30 km/s, the asteroid will totally disintegrate. The energy involved in the collision between an oxygen atom in the asteroid and an oxygen atom in the Earth is about 75 eV, which is way more than the binding energy. So, the chemical bonds between the atoms in the matter directly involved in the collision get broken. You have to picture the collision between the solid objects as if they become one big liquid mass.